# how to select just one RadioButton with RecyclerView android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, radio-button

I have a RecyclerView with RadioButton I just want to select one RadioButton not many in the same time and my code make it works fine, but when I repeat the selection from top to bottom the select disappear how can I fix it please thanks.

[image]

```
private RadioButton lastCheckedRB = null;

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ContactUsModel contactUsModel = orderList.get(position);
    holder.orderNum.setText(contactUsModel.getOrderNum());
    holder.orderCost.setText(contactUsModel.getOrderCost());

    holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
            RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);

            if (lastCheckedRB != null &&lastCheckedRB.isChecked()) {
                lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
            }
            //store the clicked radiobutton
            lastCheckedRB = checked_rb;


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do as,Use RadioButton I just write without check But this is an hint for you -

```
 private CompoundButton lastCheckedRB = null;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ContactUsModel contactUsModel = orderList.get(position);
    holder.orderNum.setText(contactUsModel.getOrderNum());
    holder.orderCost.setText(contactUsModel.getOrderCost());
    holder.readioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ls);
    holder.readioBtn.setTag(position);
}

private OnCheckedChangeListener ls = (new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        int tag = (int) buttonView.getTag();
        ;
        if (lastCheckedRB == null) {
            lastCheckedRB = buttonView;
        } else if (tag != (int) lastCheckedRB.getTag()) {
            lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
            lastCheckedRB = buttonView;
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need keep the position with `Tag` or to reload the list with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. 
Just use `checkedRadioButton` and toggle it. Then you can use `checkedRadioButton` to get the selected item.

```
private var checkedRadioButton: CompoundButton? = null

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.radio_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener)
    if (holder.itemView.radio_button.isChecked) checkedRadioButton = holder.itemView.radio_button
}

private val checkedChangeListener = CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
    checkedRadioButton?.apply { setChecked(!isChecked) }
    checkedRadioButton = compoundButton.apply { setChecked(isChecked) }
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works, thank you. Question: Is there a way to select one item as the default value?

Comment: I would add `private var defaultCheckedItemIdOrPosition` and in `onBindViewHolder` if `checkedRadioButton` is null and item is `defaultCheckedItemIdOrPosition`, check it :
`if(checkedRadioButton == null && defaultCheckedItemIdOrPosition == itemIdOrPosition) holder.itemView.radio_button.checked = true`

Comment: Where exactly do I get `itemItOrPosition`. Or do you mean `defaultCheckedItemId` is either the item.id or the position and therefore I can check `if(position == myWantedPosition) dostuff()` yes?

Comment: I like this approach since he isnt using notifyDataSetChanged which seems like an overkill for these situations

Answer (score 1):

Use One temp Variable  in your `orderList`

ex: `isSelected  = false;`

Make sure this is added in all object of your `arrayList`

When u selects any radio button just update current position `orderList` `isSelected = true` and remaining `isSelected = false`;

and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

also make sure you are checking

```
if(isSelcted)
redioButton.setChecked(true);
else
redioButton.setChecked(false);
```

ex:
 if(csSelectedAddressPos == position)
                holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
            else
                holder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);

```
        holder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //set object isChecked here 
                csSelectedAddressPos = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

I know I am way way way late to reply to this thread but if anyone in the future gets stuck in a similar problem please use the below example to resolve it, especially with `RadioButton` on `RecyclerView` :

At the TOP:

```
        //initialize as Global variable below variable

        int lastSelectedPosition = -1;// you can use any value but keep it 
         //at negative because array numbering starts at the positive
        int tempPosition;
        
        //Below code inside onBindViewHolder() function of RecyclerView
        //selectedRadio is my RadioButton

        holder.selectedRadio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, 
             boolean b) 
             {

            tempPosition = position;//getting position of click radioButton

            if (lastSelectedPosition != position)//checking last position 
               //and present position
            {
                holder.selectedRadio.setChecked(true);
                
                if (lastSelectedPosition != -1){
                   
                   //very Important code below line where the magic happens
                   notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);

                }

                lastSelectedPosition = tempPosition;
            }
        }
    });
```

That's all, waaalaaaa..Tat tara raaaaaa...
now your radio button is working as you have wanted it.

Thank you.

Answer (score -5):

1st: get individual radio button id.
2nd: assign click listener to individual radio button.

say you have 6 radio buttons:

```
{



radioButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        radioButton1.setChecked(true);
                        radioButton2.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton3.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton4.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton5.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton6.setChecked(false);
                    }
                });
```

//similarly add listeners to all radio buttons:

```
radioButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        radioButton2.setChecked(true);
                        radioButton1.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton3.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton4.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton5.setChecked(false);
                        radioButton6.setChecked(false);
                    }
                });


}
```